# Object is moving to world vector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `playerAttack()` method which gets activated when the player clicks left mouse button (condition is in a `FixedUpdate()` because of physics). The method has a Raycast which should push enemies in front of the player away. The problem is that the enemy is pushed in the world direction because of `Vector3`. I tried to use `AddRelativeForce()` instead of `AddForce()`, but it's still moving in the world direction. Here is the code:

```
public void playerAttack()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position, player.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        if (hit.rigidbody != null && hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            hit.rigidbody.AddForce(hit.rigidbody.transform.forward * weaponPush);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should take a look at `InverseTransformDirection` : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html

Comment: `Vector3 dir = hit.transform.InverseTransformDirection(0, 0, 10);`
`hit.rigidbody.AddForce(dir * weaponPush);` didn't change anything. It still flies to world direction.

Comment: Are you sure the rigidbody is correctly oriented ? Check its forward vector in the SceneView when the you hit with the raycast.

Comment: It's forward vector is `(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. Screenshot of the cubes rigidbody: https://i.snag.gy/0CwPHz.jpg

Comment: If its forward vector is (0, 0, 1) **at runtime** too (this is what I wanted to know with my previous question), and since you have frozen its rotation, then, the object will always move according to the world in the world coordinate system.

Comment: But I want to push the enemy away in players Z direction, not the worlds Z direction.

Comment: Then, why don't you use the player forward vector ? `hit.rigidbody.AddForce(player.transform.forward * weaponPush);` You've never specified you wanted to push along the forward vector of the player

Comment: That worked, thanks! My mistake was to code `hit.transform.forward` instead of `player.transform.forward`. Sorry if I wasn't clear, my english is not the best. You can post your answer so I can choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your rigidbody to be pushed away from the player, you will have to use the `player.transform.forward` vector instead of the rigidbody's one :

```
public void playerAttack()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position, player.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        if (hit.rigidbody != null && hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            hit.rigidbody.AddForce(player.transform.forward * weaponPush);
        }
    }    
}
```